# Create domain glassfish

Tags: bash, glassfish

I'm trying create a domain on glassfish. 
but, when I execute the command:

```
create-domain --adminport 4848 domain1
```

I get this message:

```
/exports/home/admapps/cf.out (No such file or directory)
Disk IO error. Not enough free space in users HOME directory to complete operation. Aborting operation.
CLI130 Could not create domain, domain1
```

I think that this is because directory  **/exports/home/** not exist, but instead I have a directory named **/export/home/**

Does somebody know how can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solve this i take several hours.
the user has permission over directory /exports/home/.... when the correct was /export/home.....

i put this command

```
usermod -m -d /export/home/admapp userName
```

and re-install.
it works!!

greetings!!